# How to resolve the confusing point about Generic in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types

I have a ts function, writing with Generic.

```js
function task<T>(builder: (props: { propsA: number }, option: T) => void) {
  return {
    run: (option: T) => {},
  }
}
```

when i use the function, the type about Generic do not work.

```js
task((props, { name = 'default name' }) => {
  /**
   * At here, We can infer the type of props: { propsA: number; }
   */
}).run('wrong option'/** But here, no type tips about param of the function call */)
```

As stated in the comment，the ts Generic cannot infer the type of T, which should be { name?: string }

But it can be fixed, when i use a separated parameters

```js
const builder = (props, { message = 'your message' }) => {
  /**
   * At here, We CANNOT infer the type of props
   */
}
task(builder).run({ message: 'correct type' } /** Correct type tips */)
```

In this form, we can refer the correct type of Generic, but lost the type infer for "props".

**What'is the primary reason about the difference?  Is there a perfect solution?**

Comment: You could pass it like: `task<{name: string}>(....)` or use a parameter name and annotate it with the desired interface like: `task((props, x: { name: string }) => {
  console.log(props, x);
}).run({ name: "bla" });`

Comment: @r3dst0rm Thanks for the answer, it's a useful solution in ts. But i want to use the ts function just in js file, i mixed the ts and js in a react project. Ts is only used in some common file, the task function is included. And i use the task function only in another js file. I want to use the  Generic feather to infer the type from ` { message = 'your message' }`, is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

For my experience in TS, I don't think you can infer T when it's in sublevel.
In your exemple T is always undefined. But if you change with :

```
function task<T, U = T extends (props: { propsA: number }, option: infer V) => void ? V : never>(builder: T) {
    return {
      run: (option: U) => {},
    }
  }
```

Normally that will work !

Comment: It can infer the option type correctly, but the props type is not work(any). I think it's very close to the perfect solution. Can you improve it? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's the better I can do :

`function task<T extends (props: {propsA: number}, option: any) => void,U = T extends (props: { propsA: number }, option: infer V) => void ? unknown extends V ? void : V : void>(builder: T) {return { run: (option: U) => {},}}`

I defined the type of builder but I don't really know why when enter the args the type change to any. And I add a security on U. If option is not defined, run doesn't need any parameter

Comment: Thanks a lot. The above solution is still not work, but i find a perfect solution.

Comment: function task<
  V,
  T extends (props: { propsA: number }, option: V) => void,
  U = T extends (props: { propsA: number }, option: infer V) => void
    ? void extends V
      ? void
      : V
    : void
>(builder: T) {
  return { run: (option: U) => {} }
}

type about props and options works well.